# How to access static variable initialised with @Mock in spring boot in Junit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the below component class.

```
 @Component
 class ComponentClass{
     private static AnotherClass anotherClass;

     @Autowired
     private void setAnotherClass(AnotherClass a){
          anotherClass = a;
     }

     public AnotherClass getAnotherClass(){
          return anotherClass;
     }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ComponentClassTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ComponentClass componentClass;

    @Mock
    private AnotherClass anotherClass;

    @Test
    public void testGetAnotherClass() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(ComponentClass.getAnotherClass());
    }
}
```

When I am trying to run the test case, getAnotherClass method is returning null. 
Can anyone help here why a mocked instance is not getting returned by getAnotherClass method call.

Comment: It will mock fields not statics.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @m-deinum: The sample has a *static* field with a *non-static* setter. This is bad practice for many reasons (including that Mockito will not touch it). Spring will, by default, ensure AnotherClass is a singleton so I suggest setting it via a constructor parameter. Both Spring and Mockito will be happy with that.

```java
private final AnotherClass anotherClass;
public ComponentClass(AnotherClass anotherClass) {
  this.anotherClass = anotherClass;
}
```